# Error when i install python=3.6.4 version in my virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, cd

I am trying to install python version 3.6.4 on my virtual environment but having errors.

I tried using pip install python==3.6.4 but this is giving me error.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.6.4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.6.4

Comment: pip isn't the right tool to do what you want to do. i suggest installing [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and doing: `conda create -n env_name python=3.6.4`, then activate it: `conda activate env_name`. this creates a "virtual environment" with the python version you have specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `pip` to install `python`. `pip` is a package powered by `python`. If you want to use a different version of Python within your virtualenv, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544).